# Kibana dashboard filter by keyword content

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard

I'm new to Kibana.

I've created a saved search that returns something like.

```
| metric     | data.counter.count |
-----------------------------------
| bob_red    | 300                |
| mark_blue  | 274                |
| bob_black  | 274                |
```

I would like, to create a dashboard with a combo box where you can select names and one where you can select colours(parsed from the field metric) and display the results accordingly in some diagrams.

Is this possible in Kibana?

Answer (score 0):

In Kibana you can use the "control" vizualization to filter a dashboard on one of your data.
So if you want to search either for "bob" either for "red" you will have to split the value in 2 different keyword fields and add a dropbox for eeach (2 dropbox can be dependent)

Note that you can also use the search bar with KQL, of the filters below this bar to do it by yourself.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/packetbeat/current/kibana-queries-filters.html